# Python isn't posting to Sqlite3 Db

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm hoping someone can point a mistake I've made.... I can manually post to the db file through the terminal, but when I run the python script no data posts to the table.

```
def logDoors(door):
    conn =  sqlite3.connect('doorlog_db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history (date REAL, door TEXT)')
    date = format(datetime.datetime.now())
    c.execute("INSERT INTO history (date, door) VALUES (?, ?)",
            (date, door))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Your database and your python file in the same directory? How do you run the python file?

Comment: They are both in the same directory, it is run through terminal on a raspberry pi as sudo.

Comment: Do you run the python file in the same directory that contains the database file?

Comment: Yes it is all run out of cd ~ which is where the script and db are.

Comment: This code runs fine for me. Are you 100% positive the `logDoors` function is actually called? If so, does the program run to completion without raising an exception? If so, does the database file actually get created? Does it have a `history` table?

Comment: The db file gets created, no errors when running. I had added some print statements in the function and they all printed. and I am 100% sure the logDoors gets called. I am plugging a "name" variable into the function which is the "door" name. Hopefully you can make sense of this even though it isn't formatted all pretty here. `for pinNumber, name in pins.items():
                try:
                        alarmTripped=False

                        if (GPIO.input(pinNumber) == 0):
                                logDoors(name)
`

Comment: It works fine for me. Others comments say if works fine for them too.  So I think the code is okay.  Maybe check the ownership and permissions of the database.  Delete the database and let the logDoors function create if again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're connecting to a file with no extension. Did you try this?

```
conn =  sqlite3.connect('doorlog_db.sqlite')
```

Comment: I just tried that, didn't work any differently. Still no data in table.

Comment: I just tried your original code and works fine for me

Comment: You might not be able to catch the Exception because of the "try" statement

Comment: I can try removing the try, I'm in python 3 though

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was actually an issue with the db reading program I was using. The two db's had been created with differential extensions. The db reader didn't recognize the file with the _db as a file it could open even though it could. Therefore I was opening the .db file which wasn't being wrote to.